# "Explain this code to me" disguised as "Explain part of this code to me"

Tags: discussion, help-vampire

I recently answered a question asking for explanation of part of an algorithm the asker had found somewhere. I then received a dozen comments requesting further clarification. It seems this user is avoiding having their questions closed by asking about a detail in the code, and then expanding the question in comments until it's basically "explain this whole algorithm to me".
They also seem to be using "I'm debugging this code" as a euphemism for "I found this code somewhere".

Should I answer questions like this? Downvote? Talk to the user about their help-vampirism? Flag for moderator intervention? Or just ignore and move on?

Look at the comment section of the answers in these examples:

- [suffix tree implementation issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32980460/suffix-tree-implementation-issue)
- [generating k prime numbers using Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33009476/generating-k-prime-numbers-using-sieve-of-eratosthenes)
- [use a single array to implement three stacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33110047/use-a-single-array-to-implement-three-stacks)
- [hash value for a line object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33052068/hash-value-for-a-line-object) (with Jon Skeet as the "victim")
- [using 10 MB of memory for four billion integers (about finding the optimized block size)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33050047/using-10-mb-of-memory-for-four-billion-integers-about-finding-the-optimized-blo)

Here's a fresh one if you want to follow all the latest action live:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33135241/find-maximum-rectangle-which-rows-and-columns-are-all-valid-words

Comment: The code being "debugged" appears to be a variation on [this](http://ctci.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Java/Chapter%2018/Question18_13/Question.java)

Comment: Perhaps it is as simple as asking and answering the following question for yourself: can my effort help anyone else besides the OP? In the way these questions end up needing to be handled consistently, I don't really think so. I wonder of informing the user of their behavior can have any effect either, it all seems pretty much intelligently calculated. I wish those smarts were put to work to do proper study.

Comment: Help vampires... at some point I find it's usually necessary to just tell them "Good luck" after exhausting my patience.

Comment: OK, I guess my question is sort of answered by the duplicate. Anyway, thanks to everyone who responded here!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think downvoting and don't looking back would be my first option. If I think there's [a human being](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_the_Internet,_nobody_knows_you%27re_a_dog) worth the effort on the other side, I'd comment and try to give some guidance.

Voting to close, or flagging it as off-topic, would be the next step.

But, really, all of this it's up to you, all the tools are there: answer, comment, vote, flag. But not Mod intervention, it's not their work look for bad content or this kind of bad behaviour.

If you want to understand the vampire soul and go for the ride, reading this is a must: [The Help Vampire problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19665/185667).

Answer (score 2):

These all sound to me like classic cases of bad content. There are flags and other means (downvote/comment) to let users who do this know that their content is low quality, and even if they don't listen, downvoting/voting to close/flagging can still protect others from these "questions".