# Is this "Explain this code to me" question on topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope

Recently I found and answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45066119/3745896). It garnered quite a few downvotes and before I posted my answer the only upvote on it was mine.

I feel most downvoters fell into the [hasty generalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasty_generalization) trap. (Explain the code questions are often [broad](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260466/3745896) [and](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253894/3745896) [low](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/278797/3745896) [quality](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271468/3745896).) However, there are a few commenters who have, I would hope, read the question in more depth and still feel it is clearly off topic.

Most meta answers (see broad/low quality links above) on the topic agree that if a "explain the code" question is specific and clear about what is not understood, it is solidly on-topic.

The question is well-written, clearly points out what confuses the OP, and shows effort exerted to understand on their own before bringing the question here. It does end with a broad request to explain the code, but it seems implied that only the sections indicated really need clarification (I edited it slightly but this seemed implied even in the original). It also doesn't seem like a case of [bait and switch](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308067/explain-this-code-to-me-disguised-as-explain-part-of-this-code-to-me).

Essentially my question is, why did so many people feel this question was off-topic and only I thought it on topic?

Comment: Particularly disturbing was the comment on the post:

*`"So, the problem is not in code but in your understanding of it which I'd consider as off-topic"`*

Suggesting that understanding code is off-topic for SO.

Comment: Well part of the problem is that it asks the really broad question of just "explain this code to me", and *then* goes on to ask a more specific question.  If the question never asks the broad question, and *only* asks the specific question about the code, then the question is *far* less likely to be interpreted as being too broad.

Comment: @Servy He does the more specific *first* and then the broad doesn't he? In either case, this seems along the lines of users flagging without fully understanding the question.

Comment: There are sentences indicating it's a much broader question both before and after the more specific question.  And no, it doesn't necessarily mean that other people didn't read the question, it could simply mean they interpreted it differently.  You read it as *only* asking the specific question, and the broader statements about a lack of understanding are effectively noise, and aren't really what the question is.  Someone else could easily interpret the post as asking *both* questions, both the specific question *and* the more broad question, making the post Too Broad.

Comment: You apparently have a higher tolerance for "debug my code for me" than others. Most people would like people to, you know, use a debugger, step through the code, see how the variables change, etc.. Not a close reason in itself, to be sure, but that, and the fact that I see three question marks there, leads me to believe that if I explained the code, there'd be multiple follow on questions.

Comment: The other users could just as easily argue that it's *you* who aren't fully understanding the question given that you're choosing to completely ignore requests for the broader explanation of the whole thing, and only addressing the more specific question.  I would argue this is a case of the question being worded poorly, and needing fixing, but my point is that such an argument isn't without merit.

Comment: @Servy that's a very good point. I guess I assumed the broad statement was showing that their specific issues impeded their understanding of the code in its entirety.

Comment: It has two close votes on it currently. I get the "too broad" close vote, although I can kind of see both sides of that argument. But I don't agree the "no MCVE" one at all. It isn't a "why isn't this code working" question. Some people seem to really want every question to be of that type, and I've never understood why.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan exactly!   Debugger, step through, inspect and record values.  Not difficult intellectually, just hard work. The questions seeks to offload that hard work onto other SO users.   I am less than impressed by any 'Explain working code' questions, many of which are just copied from other students' work or the net, and the 'author' seeks to get someone else to do the 'Clearly explain how your answer works' part of the homework:(

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan OP suggests he has already stepped through the code, either by hand or with a debugger. Seeing the numbers change doesn't give the *why* of the change. I assumed filling in that gap was the OP's holdup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Servy pointed out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352379/is-this-explain-this-code-to-me-question-on-topic#comment493603_352379), whereas I interpreted the broader parts of the question as more fluff than actual questions (e.g. "Explain this code to me, specifically this line."), the wording was such that these broader parts could be interpreted as parts of the question as well (e.g. "Explain this line to me, but also tell me how the code works in general.").

I disagree with the comments claiming this was a "debug my code for me" question and that the OP would have gotten all he needed from a debugger. From the question it seemed he had gone through the code by hand, tracing the path of execution, but even seeing the numbers change at each stage, couldn't deduce the semantic meaning of the changes. It took me a little while to grasp the reasoning behind some of the subtler changes, and I could see it being very challenging for someone inexperienced or completely new to coding.

In any case, I think the best resolution to the broad or specific ambiguity is to make it clearly specific. I have done so, editing out the broader statements and expressly stating the points to be addressed. If anyone feels there are still parts that beget broadness, feel free to edit them out as well.

Comment: Assume people have terrible reading comprehension skills, etc... a good assumption to make in most cases anyway.